# Installing keytool without JDK

Tags: linux, centos, java, docker, centos-7

I am trying to install `keytool` in a docker image based on centos but I get an error.
Example to reproduce `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM centos:7.9.2009                                                                                                                                                              


RUN yum install -y keytool
```

When I run `docker build` I get an error in the `RUN` line.

Is it possible to install `keytool` without installing `JDK`?

Comment: You don't need the full JDK, but you do need a JRE; in the RH/CentOS naming java-$ver-openjdk-devel is the JDK and java-$ver-openjdk[-headless] is the JRE, and since keytool is not GUI the (smaller) -headless version is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You may use an alternative to keytool.

For example : [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/).

[image]

Comment: I need to use `keytool` inside the docker image. This application although maybe useful in general does not fit my purpose.

Comment: Perhaps the Docker image [joostdecock/keytool](https://hub.docker.com/r/joostdecock/keytool) ?